# Retrieving Tabledata is canceled after 90 seconds

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to implement parallel retrieve of data from table using API method `Tabledata:list`.

For this I am using .NET NuGet package `Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2` and from there either method `TabledataResource.ListRequest.Execute()` or method `TabledataResource.ListRequest.ExecuteAsync()` and waiting for task to complete.

In both cases calling of this method thrown exception, that task was canceled. It happened roughly 90 seconds after calling method.

Have you experienced this? Do you have some suggestions how to change this limit? Or for some workaround?

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30
};
List<Int32> results = new List<Int32>();
const Int32 __NUM_OF_ITEMS = 10000;
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 30), po, index =>
{
    TabledataResource.ListRequest listRequest = _service.Tabledata.List(
        resultTable.ProjectId,
        resultTable.DatasetId,
        resultTable.TableId
    );
    listRequest.PageToken = pageToken;
    listRequest.StartIndex = (UInt64?) index * __NUM_OF_ITEMS;
    TableDataList tdl = listRequest.Execute();
});
```

EDITED:

I did further investigation and these are times which it took to retrieve 100 items from my table using different startIndex. PageToken was null in all cases.

```
[INF      2015-05-15 09:26:33.283] Testing retrieval speed.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:26:34.431] startIndex=0 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=1147 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:26:51.210] startIndex=1000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=16779 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:27:11.166] startIndex=2000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=19955 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:27:36.400] startIndex=3000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=25234 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:28:22.744] startIndex=4000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=46344 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:29:36.057] startIndex=5000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=73314 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:30:33.153] startIndex=6000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=57095 ms.
[INF      2015-05-15 09:31:44.062] startIndex=7000000 retrievedItems=100 timeSpent=70910 ms.
```

My table has 14M rows and I failed to get result for starting index 8M (exception described above was thrown).

Answer (score 0):

Where does your pageToken come from? There is a setMaxLimit (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Tabledata.List.html#setMaxResults(java.lang.Long)) to set the max number of results to return. Maybe you can try to issue smaller requests to see if it would success.

Comment: Check my edit. PageToken is null. I set `listRequest.MaxResults = 100`.